# Loop with dataBinding - android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-xml, android-databinding

I have two models for get values from service :

First model `FieldStudyList.class`:

```
public class FieldStudyList {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<ResultFieldStudyList> result = null;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;

    public List<ResultFieldStudyList> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<ResultFieldStudyList> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

Second model `ResultFieldStudyList.class`:

```
public class ResultFieldStudyList {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("introtext")
    @Expose
    private String introtext;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIntrotext() {
        return introtext;
    }

    public void setIntrotext(String introtext) {
        this.introtext = introtext;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I am using from `dataBinding` in my `xml` for show values but I can't show them :

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="listItems"
        type="xxx.xx.models.FieldStudyList" />
</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_lstItemStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{listItems.result.iterator() ???}"<=== I can't show title here ?
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You need to set listItems.result.get(index).title

Comment: How can I set index in get() ?

Comment: What you want to show? You have many objects inside `listItems.result`. Is Your RecyclerView expandable?

Comment: I need to show title .

Comment: Well obviously you cannot make a for loop inside xml, so it depends which list you want to show in your `recyclerView`

Comment: Take a look at: https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4 and see if it helps.